# Efecto llenado sobre imagen con Css Canvas o Svg

Tags: css, css3, canvas, svg

Necesito saber si hay alguna forma de generar un efecto de llenado de "ondas" SOBRE UNA IMAGEN PNG.
No importa si es con CSS, SVG, Canvas o alguna librería externa de javascript.
Con un pequeño ejemplo ya me ayudan bastante.

Sería algo como esto, pero sobre una imagen PNG.
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/43505d196a3df4510258183b2bd6f58e1c482f5a/687474703a2f2f672e7265636f726469742e636f2f7a48654d71716c68346a2e676966

**Esperado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-3">

<div class="well">

  <img src="https://www.hamburgsud-line.com/liner/media/hamburg_sud_liner_shipping/services/dry_cargo/20_trockencontainer_accordion_1240x697.png"style="width:100%">
  
</div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95750/

Comment: Lo que tu quieres es muy complicado. Seria más fácil si en lugar de un PNG como este,  tuvieras las imágenes sin deformar de al menos 3 paredes del contenedor.

Comment: Si fuera plano, sería posible? es decir : https://2ecffd01e1ab3e9383f0-07db7b9624bbdf022e3b5395236d5cf8.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-800x800/41ca6a69-c915-4408-b7d0-924754c2970e.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como ya te dije en mi comentario, habría necesitado tus imágenes sin deformar. Cogí algo parecido del internet. Para las olas utilizo dos elementos canvas.

En el HTML tengo un elemento #Hamburg, dentro de cual hay todas las caras de un paralelogramo. Si no te gusta la orientación, por favor cambia esta línea de código: `transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(-10deg) rotateZ(7deg);` en el CSS para el `#Hamburg`. También prueba cambiar la perspectiva del body.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let percent = .5;

const _canvas = document.getElementById("_canvas");
const _ctx = _canvas.getContext("2d");


let cw = canvas.width = 276;
let ch =_canvas.width = _canvas.height = canvas.height = 64;


let amplitude = 12;
let frequency = .053;
let phi = 0;


ctx.fillStyle = _ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";

drawSineWave(ctx,cw,0,percent);
drawSineWave(_ctx,ch,cw,percent);

function drawSineWave(ctx,w,start,percent){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
for (let x = 0; x <= w; x++) {
    let y = Math.sin((start + x) * frequency + phi) * amplitude / 2 + ch*(1-percent);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y); // 40 = offset
  }
ctx.lineTo(w,0);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
}



function Draw() {
requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
_ctx.clearRect(0,0,ch,ch);
phi += .1;  

drawSineWave(ctx,cw,0,percent);
drawSineWave(_ctx,ch,cw,percent);
}
Draw();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 400px;
}

#Hamburg {  
  height: 64px;
  width: 276px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(-10deg) rotateZ(7deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.face {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;  
  background-color:hsl(358,76%,45%);
  height: 64px;
  width: 276px;
  background: hsl(358,76%,45%);
}

#canvas {
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/Hamburg.png');
}
#_canvas {
  background: hsl(358,76%,40%);
}

.left {
  width: 64px;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background:gold;
}

.right {
  width: 64px;
  transform: translateX(276px) translateZ(64px) rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  background:hsl(357,78%,16%)
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(64px); 
  ttransform-origin: top left;
  
}

.back {}
```

```html
<div id="Hamburg">
  <div class="face back"></div>
  <div class="face left"></div>
  <div class="face right"><canvas id="_canvas"></canvas></div>
  <div class="face top"></div>
  <div class="face bottom"></div>
  <div class="face front"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Y en caso de ser una imagen plana? de que manera lo podría implementar, por ejemplo : https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/c/c9/Football_Ball.png/revision/latest?cb=20100104174227

Comment: No se si te entiendo muy bien: o sea ahora quieres cambiar la pregunta. Ya no quieres el contenedor de Hamburg Süd sino una pelota? Para mi una pelota no es una imagen plana sino una esfera o un poliedro complejo. Si quieres "un efecto de llenado" para una pelota, creo que esta sería otra pregunta.

Comment: Claro, la pregunta concreta sería, si se podría aplicar la misma lógica a una imagen 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te podría ayudar a lograr lo que quieres. 
Solo debes ir aumentando la propiedad cada "x" milisegundos.

Te incluyo el ejemplo:

```
cnt.innerHTML = percent;
water.style.transform = 'translate(0, ' + (100 - percent) + '%)';
water.querySelector('.water__inner').style.height = percent + '%';
```

Link de [fuente](https://codepen.io/MikitaLisavets/pen/PZqPZE)